# Windows 8 hang on startup and chkdsk /f /r

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, hardware-failure, chkdsk

Trying to fix a friends Lenovo p400 laptop. The drive is a samsung spin point one terabyte drive.

The system hangs during booting, will go into system recovery, or the uefi firmware settings screen.

I was able to log into windows 8 after a few power cycles.

I got a chkdsk c: /f /r but it seems to be hanging at ten percent.

Any thoughts on what the problem is? Dying hard drive?

[image: blue screen]

[image: chkdsk]

Comment: "0xc000000e" in my experiences typically means file corruption of winload.exe or other boot related files; the fact that you can get to checkdisk at all is a good sign.

Comment: Lenovo has a factory reset feature. Besides that can I repair the boot files?

Comment: Since you are no longer getting that error, and can boot up to run checkdisk, Windows has probably replaced the corrupted files using sxs backups, so there shouldn't be a need to repair any files manually. I can't help with the checkdisk issue, sorry.

Comment: You might find this post interesting. It took a user 72hours for his to complete. http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1zml5f/chkdsk_r_stuck_at_10/

Comment: Yes interesting. I didn't know about chkdsk /v . Also would a sfc /scannow help?

Comment: I've never used the tool, but it sounds cool.

Comment: Someone pointed me to bcdedit.exe to repair corrupt boot files.